# android html formatting subscript getting cut off

Tags: android, html, formatting, subscript

As the title eludes to, I am using HTML in my text strings. It is working but the   entity is getting cut off at the bottom.

```
    <string name="test" formatted="false">
D&#x2080;&lt;sub&gt;50&lt;/sub&gt; 50% Dextrose
</string>




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/versionpadding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/versionpadding"
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:text="@string/test">
        </TextView>

    TextView Textview_test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    Textview_test.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test)));
```

but the issue is the top half of the subscript is showing in the appropriate placement, but the bottom is cut off.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the folowing:

```
D&#x2080;&lt;sub&gt;&lt;small&gt;50&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/sub&gt; 50% Dextrose
```

You could also specify html content in xml as below:

```
<string name="test"><Data><![CDATA[<b>HTML from String resource in android</b>]]></Data></string>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it still didn't work. the '&#x2080;' came up as a box and when I removed it, the subscript 50 was cut off.

Comment: can you post an image for the same?